# Simulating existing panel data in R

Tags: r, simulation, panel

I need to create a simulated dataset, that matches distributions and correlations of the original data. The original data is a panel, with the variable "id_worker" denoting individuals, and the varibale "year" denoting the various waves.

Some variables are string (for instance "sex"), some other are numeric (for instance "wage"); also some variable may change over time, while others are fixed within individual.

I have been trying to use the package sim_df from the library faux, but I am struggling in understanding how to use its option.

As an example, consider the dataset Grunfeld which has a variable "firm" which is an id, a variable "year" to denote time and three variables ("inv", "value", "capital") to denote characterstics of these firm. Running

```
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
fake <- sim_df(Grunfeld)
```

does not respect the panel structure of the original data, and the fake data ends up having non-integer values of "year" or "firm".

```
fake <- sim_df(Grunfeld, between="firm", within = "year", dv =  c("inv", "value", "capital"),  long=TRUE)
```

gives me the following error:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(data, c(id, between, within, dv)) :
> undefined columns selected

Going through the examples in the documentation didn't help.

I'd really appreciate any guidance on the syntax of this package, or indication of another way of achieving what I need.

Thanks in advance!